# Upper bounds for E(f(x))

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, expected-value

Given a discrete random variable X, with finite mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ and a convex function f(x), what is the tighter upper bound one can give for E(f(x))? I am looking for something in this line: [Lower-bound for $E(\log{((x+1)!)}$)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4815342/lower-bound-for-e-logx1/4815388?noredirect=1#comment10246727_4815388) . Maybe that's the best, I'm just curious. Does the result have a well-known name or a paper associated?